# An accepted answer on a bountied question did not award the bounty

Tags: support, bounty

[Firebase Dynamic Links - Can't get Url in android after install app from play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188909/firebase-dynamic-links-cant-get-url-in-android-after-install-app-from-play-st/51346429#51346429)

I have provided the answer on this question during the bounty period, and it was accepted during the grace period; however, I have not been awarded any bounty for this answer.  What's going on?  Could someone please clarify?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless the benefactor (e.g. the person that offered the bounty) was the OP, bounties are not automatically awarded to an accepted answer.  Normally, it has to be manually awarded it to a person, or the system itself will award it to a question which has the highest score among questions which scored 2 or more during the bounty period.  If your answer scored 2 or more, was the highest voted answer amongst qualified answers, *and* was accepted, you would be awarded the full amount; otherwise, you would only qualify for half.

In this case, the benefactor simply didn't award anyone the bounty, so no one earned anything.  Also, [another user offered the bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51188909/timeline#vote_166862350) instead, so the automatic award for an accepted answer would not be triggered.
  This happens sometimes; the answers provided during the bounty period fell below the threshold for qualifying for an automatic award.

For more details, [peruse this Help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on how bounties work.

Comment: "If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration." I think this happened because it was accepted during the grace period.

Comment: @user2285236:  [In this case the OP was not the benefactor.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51188909/timeline#vote_166862350)  I'll update my answer to include that point.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that.

Comment: @user2285236-thanks. should i  notify to benefactor for this case.But it does not make sense the OP accepted answer but benefactor not awarded any bounty

Comment: @NullPointer:  No, there's nothing you can do about it.  Best to just move on.

Comment: @Makoto what will happen if person who created bounty did not accept my answer during bounty or grace period but after grace period ended?